# concatinating tensors :Dimension out of range (expected to be in range of [-1, 0], but got 1)

Tags: pytorch

Im building a diffusion model and im training it on data uniformly distributed :points inside a square, ranging from x = −1, y = −1 to x = 1, y = 1.

this is my code:

```
import torch
from torch import linalg as LA
import plotly.express as px
from plotly.subplots import make_subplots
import plotly.graph_objects as go
from torch.utils.data import TensorDataset, DataLoader, Dataset
import torch.optim as optim
import torch.nn as nn
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from tqdm import tqdm
lr = 0.001
num_data = 3000
batch_size = 3000
num_epochs = 3000
x_dim = 2  # dimension of input
beta1 = 0.5  # Beta1 hyperparameter for Adam optimizers
l2 = nn.MSELoss()
colors = px.colors.qualitative.T10
MODEL_PATH = 'denoiser.pth'
CONDITIONAL_MODEL_PATH = 'denoiser_conditional.pth'# the denoiser
class NetD(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(NetD, self).__init__()
        # intput: [x0, x1, t]
        self.fc = nn.Sequential(
            nn.Linear(x_dim + 1, (x_dim + 1) * 8),
            nn.LeakyReLU(0.2, inplace=True),
            nn.Linear((x_dim + 1) * 8, (x_dim + 1) * 20),
            nn.LeakyReLU(0.2, inplace=True),
            nn.Linear((x_dim + 1) * 20, x_dim),
            # output: [e0, e1]
        )

    def forward(self, x_t):
        return self.fc(x_t)
sigma = lambda t0: torch.exp(5 * (t0 - 1))
sigma_tag = lambda t0: 5 * torch.exp(5 * (t0 - 1))
SNR = lambda t0: 1 / sigma(t0) ** 2
#training denoiser
def train_denoiser(netD):
    # training
    dataset = TensorDataset(data)
    dataloader = DataLoader(dataset=dataset, shuffle=True, batch_size=batch_size, num_workers=2)
    optimizer = optim.Adam(netD.parameters(), lr=lr, betas=(beta1, 0.999))

    losses = []
    for _ in tqdm(range(num_epochs)):
        for i, x0 in enumerate(dataloader):
            netD.zero_grad()
            x0 = x0[0].to(device)
            real_noise = torch.randn(x0.shape, device=device)
            t = torch.rand(x0.shape[0], 1, device=device)
            xt = x0 + sigma(t) * real_noise
            xt_t = torch.cat((xt, t), dim=1)
            pred_noise = netD(xt_t)
            loss = l2(pred_noise, real_noise)
            loss.backward()
            optimizer.step()
            losses.append(loss.item())
    torch.save(netD.state_dict(), MODEL_PATH)
    return losses
# # save model
# torch.save(netD.state_dict(), MODEL_PATH)
import os

# Define the directory where you want to save the model
save_dir = '/content/saved_models'

# Create the directory if it doesn't exist
os.makedirs(save_dir, exist_ok=True)

# Save the model in the specified directory
MODEL_PATH = os.path.join(save_dir, 'denoiser.pth')
#torch.save(netD.state_dict(), MODEL_PATH)

def load_denoiser(conditional=False):
    # load saved model
    if conditional:
        net = NetDConditional().to(device)
        net.load_state_dict(torch.load(CONDITIONAL_MODEL_PATH, map_location=device))
    else:
        net = NetD().to(device)
        net.load_state_dict(torch.load(MODEL_PATH, map_location=device))
    return net
@torch.no_grad()
def sample(netD, xt, T=1000, return_trajectory=False, additional_noise=False):
    dt = -1. / T
    num = xt.shape[0]
    traj = [xt.detach().clone()]
    if additional_noise:  # add a little noise in the modified sampler
        xt += torch.randn(xt.shape).to(device) * 0.1
    ts_10 = torch.arange(1.0, 0.0, dt, device=device)
    for t in ts_10:
        ts = (t.unsqueeze(dim=0)).repeat(num, 1)
        print(ts.shape)
        print(xt.shape)
        est_noise = netD(torch.cat((xt, ts), dim=1))
        x0_hat = xt - sigma(t) * est_noise
        score_x = (x0_hat - xt) / sigma(t) ** 2
        dx = -sigma_tag(t) * sigma(t) * score_x * dt
        xt += dx
        traj.append(xt.detach().clone())
    if return_trajectory:
        return traj
    
    return xt
# Create the denoiser model
netD = NetD().to(device)

# Train the denoiser
train_denoiser(netD)

# Save the denoiser model
torch.save(netD.state_dict(), 'denoiser.pth')

# Load the denoiser model
netD = load_denoiser()

# Convert the data to tensors and move them to the device
data_tensor = data.to(device)

# Apply the diffusion process using the sample function
diffused_points = sample(netD, data_tensor, T=1000)
```

the training worked well and produced the desired results.
Then I wanted to see how the model performs on points outside the square  x = −1, y = −1 to x = 1, y = 1.

and this is my code . first i created a point and added to it noise during the forward process.

```
xf = torch.tensor([2.835, 5.3], device=device)
ts_01 = torch.arange(0, 1.0, 0.001)
xs = []
for t in ts_01:
        xs.append(xf)
        noise = torch.randn(xf.shape, device=device)
        xf = xf + sigma(t) * noise

x, y = torch.t(torch.stack(xs)).cpu()
fig = px.scatter(x=x, y=y, color=ts_01.cpu(), title="Forward process: noised dot (2.835, 5.3) over time t",
                     color_continuous_scale="jet")
fig.show()


print(xf.shape)
print(xf)


torch.Size([2])
tensor([-13.1604,   1.0097])
```

then i wanted to see how the model performed :

```
@torch.no_grad()
def sample_2(netD, xt, T=1000, return_trajectory=False, additional_noise=False):
    dt = -1. / T
    num = xt.shape[0]
    traj = [xt.detach().clone()]
    if additional_noise:  # add a little noise in the modified sampler
        xt += torch.randn(xt.shape).to(device) * 0.1
    
    ts_10 = torch.arange(1.0, 0.0, dt, device=device)
    
    for t in ts_10:
        ts = t.unsqueeze(dim=0).repeat(1, num)
        
        print(ts.shape)
        print(ts)
        est_noise = netD(torch.cat((xt, ts), dim=1))
        x0_hat = xt - sigma(t) * est_noise
        score_x = (x0_hat - xt) / sigma(t) ** 2
        dx = -sigma_tag(t) * sigma(t) * score_x * dt
        xt += dx
        traj.append(xt.detach().clone())
    if return_trajectory:
        return traj
    return xt


denoised_single_point=sample_2(netD,xf,T=1000)
```

and i get the following error :

```
Dimension out of range (expected to be in range of [-1, 0], but got 1)
```

and it seems that the problem is here :

```
est_noise = netD(torch.cat((xt, ts), dim=1))
```

this is how the ts looks :
torch.Size([1, 2])
tensor([[1., 1.]])

and this is the xf:
tensor([-13.1604,   1.0097])
torch.Size([2])
i cant seem to understand what is the problem is it a dimensionality problem between xf and ts ?

I tried to change the dimentionality of xf :

```
xt_reshaped = xt.unsqueeze(dim=1)
```

but got the following error :
mat1 and mat2 shapes cannot be multiplied (2x2 and 3x24)

thank you and would be happy for your help  :)

Answer (score 0):

xt_reshaped = xt.unsqueeze(dim=0) fixed it

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**